# How to Set UILabel Position Programmatically iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uilabel, xcode5

I migrated to Xcode 5 and started programming for iOS 7. I am trying to set the position of my labels manually (programmatically) to produce different layouts for iPhone 4 devices and iPhone 5 devices. I suppose this should be very easy as follows:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 21);
```

At least all the articles on *StackOverflow* said to do it this way, but it is not working with me. The label doesn't change position no matter what values I enter in `CGRectMake`. I even tried the same code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but didn't work too. If I `NSLog` the new coordinates it shows me that it took them, but on the simulator no change in the label position.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you force a screen refresh, `[yourView setNeedsDisplay]`?

Comment: you added this as subview of something or self.view ? is added as subview.. please check relative to the parent view..

Comment: try adding your label code in ViewWillAppear

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` didn't work, I tried it.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` didn't work either. The only thing worked so far was the idea of turning off Autolayout (suggested below), but I am afraid that due to this I have to manually set everything now, and I don't want that. I just want some items to be manually set..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to switch off the main view's "Use Autolayout" flag in Interface Builder.
Auto Layout is enabled by default when you create a new project.

[image]

Comment: Won't this affect all the views in all my project? I want the Autolauout to work for some views (or items) but not all views.

Comment: Stopping it works, but does this mean I need to manually set the position of everything now?

Comment: You can have both views with Autolayout set and without this feature - but you have to decide whether to use it on a certain view or not. There's an Apple doc about this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH15-SW1

Comment: Or you might try out to encapsulate the UILabel in a view (which is the size of the full view for example) and disable in this view the AutoLayout. Haven't tried but the referenced Apple doc mentions some words on this and also in Interface Builder you can specify this flag on every view...

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad try to call

`[self.view frame];`

This will force redraw screen. :)

I know, it looks like indus code, but sometimes it helps :)

Comment: then make sure that you don't change label's frame in other methods.
Check all VC's methods : 
viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear: , viewDidAppear, etc...